# UIWebView transparency breaks my code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am setting the background color of a `UIWebView` to clearColor and am also setting the `opaque` property to false.

In my html file I have set the background to transparent. However for some weird reason my web view doesn't interpret the body of my HTML file correctly, I see tags like `<b><i>` etc. As soon as I remove the setBackgroundColor: call things return to normal. This happens on the iOS 5 simulator.

```
 [self.aWebView loadData:someData MIMEType:nil textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

And the aWebView is configured as follows:

```
self.aWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.aWebView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: can we see your uiwebview code? maybe even how you are loading the html file?

Comment: Sure, I have posted some code.